# Problem to create another database with Spring

Tags: spring, database, quartz

I've worked in a project (using Spring) that connect with in another database and it brings any tables, fields and datas of this database.

And now I need to create a new local database with this informations, but I didnt get it with Spring framework.

I only managed to create a new schema and tables in my local database.

I need to create a new database using spring framework. Can someone help me about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your local database manually, and connect your spring boot application to this new database. To do this, you just have to update your configuration file :

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/my_new_db
    username: my_user
    password: ***
```

Comment: Hi gantoin, thanks for reply me, but I need to create the database dinamically. One example: A customer put his datasource information in my app and then my app connect in his database and get tables, fields and data. This is the reason what my app needs to create dinamically the database. I hope to see clear in my explanation.

Comment: If a customer put his database informations on your file properties, your app will connect to it. You want that it create a new database but Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) not the data source on his machine. You should probably create a shell script to do this or dockerize your app.